# Angular2: ControlGroup inside ControlArray

Tags: forms, angular

I’m having a hard time figuring out how to iterate over a `ControlArray` that contains `Controlgroup`s in a template. In TypeScript, so far I have created the `ControlArray`, and by iterating over data received from a remote service, I added a few `ControlGroup`s to the array. Everything fine up to this point, and I can see the expected data structure in the console.

In the template, I have this:

```
<div *ngFor="#c of categories.controls">
    <div ngControlGroup="c">
    </div>
</div>
```

... where `categories` is the ControlArray (which holds an array of `ControlGroup`s in its `controls` property). When I leave out the inner `<div>`,  I don’t get an error, which suggests that Angular agrees with me that `categories.controls` is indeed an array. But as soon as I re-add the inner `<div>` (where I expect the local variable `c` to be one of the objects in the array), I get an exception with message “Cannot find control 'c' in [c in ]”. Also, I tried various other syntactical approaches, but none of them worked. In addition to a “Cannot find control …” method I also got “Cannot find a differ supporting object …”, but that didn’t take me any further.

Any hints regarding what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a Plunker?

Comment: Here you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/l4r2snv6QLFZl6pM84VC?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngControlGroup` is defining a new control group. If I understand your question correctly, you want to actually be editing items within a control group inside a control array. Check out this plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/3gM2TuMGBW13HNATUcCO

```
<div *ngFor="#c of categories.controls; #i = index">
      Control group {{i}}:
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-b" [ngFormControl]="c.controls.title"/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-b" [ngFormControl]="c.controls.id"/>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: The key was actually changing `ngControl` to `[ngFormControl]`in my Plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/UCwXTkcMuBQExA7p38TV). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One error is

```
ngControlGroup="c"
```

which doesn't do any binding. It passes the literal `c` to `ngControlGroup`. It should be:

```
[ngControlGroup]="c"
```

The errors that are still produced after this fix seem because there are no controls.

Answer (score 1):

Error is resolved by changing

```
ngControlGroup="c"
```

into

```
attr.ngControlGroup="c"
```

Because by assigning `c` to `ngControlGroup` you are just assigning the value instead of any binding. but strange why `[ngControlGroup]` still produces some error.apart from these here is working example 
https://plnkr.co/edit/Yw21a1aSivNg4G6gYkhF?p=preview

Comment: Thanks so far. I further edited your plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/UCwXTkcMuBQExA7p38TV?p=info . In the template, I added a call to a method `dump()`, which proves that `c.controls.title` is in fact a `Control`, but still, I get an error when trying to use that as value of the `ngControl` attribute in the template. Plus: the number of displayed control groups is incorrect. Any ideas?